# Can CircleCI get kicked off by something other than a repository commit?

Tags: circleci

I have successfully set up CircleCI for a github project, but my team has a use case for kicking off testing after there has been a change to an azure container in the web registry. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need  to write something that is able to be notified of the change and use the CircleCI API (https://circleci.com/docs/api/) to trigger a build.

Comment: I agree. I actually posted a related question along those lines here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752620/circleci-api-behaving-differently-from-github-commit-trigger