# CircleCI API behaving differently from github commit trigger?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm running the [cypress-example-kitchen sink app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink) on CircleCI.

This is my yaml config script:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.0.1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/install:
          build: 'npm run build'
      - cypress/run:
          requires:
            - cypress/install
          start: 'npm start'
```

This kicks off and passes just fine when I make a commit to my fork of the repo above.

However, when I try to execute a CircleCI build programmatically, using
`curl -X POST https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/Atticus29/cypress-example-kitchensink?circle-token=myApiToken`, the build fails and the jobs dashboard on CircleCI tells me that something is wrong with my config file:

> 6 schema violations found   required key [jobs] not found   workflows:
>   5 schema violations found
>       workflows: minimum size: [2], found: [1](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink)
>       workflows: build: jobs: 4 schema violations found
>         workflows: build: jobs: 0: 0 subschemas matched instead of one
>           workflows: build: jobs: 0: expected type: String, found: Mapping
>           workflows: build: jobs: 0: install: extraneous key [build] is not permitted
>         workflows: build: jobs: 1: 0 subschemas matched instead of one
>           workflows: build: jobs: 1: expected type: String, found: Mapping
>           workflows: build: jobs: 1: run: extraneous key [start] is not permitted

And that something went wrong with my build:

> Build-agent version 0.1.1216-48f80d08 (2018-12-07T16:01:40+0000)
>   Configuration errors: 2 errors occurred:
>
> - Configuration version 2.1 requires the "Enable Build Processing" project setting. Enable Build Processing under Project Settings ->
>     Advanced Settings. In order to retrigger build processing, you must
>     push a new commit.
> - Cannot find a job named `build` to run in the `jobs:` section of your configuration file. If you expected a workflow to run, check your
>     config contains a top-level key called 'workflows:'

I can confirm that Enable Build Processing is on.

None of these were problems when I ran the build in the usual way. Any advice?

Comment: Update: I have also tried curl -u personalApiToken: -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"branch":"master"}' https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/Atticus29/cypress-example-kitchensink/build?circle-token=projectApiToken and gotten a "Permission denied" result.

Comment: It is not well documented, but config version 2.1 does not work with that API endpoint yet. There is no API that supports running the 2.1 config at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circle CI for some reason keeps on assuming that the projects are not set up for v2.0 despite config.yml being called the right thing and living in the right place in the repo. After a few commits, this issue seems to go away?

I ended up running a build programmatically with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PERSONAL_TOKEN=myPersonalTokenHere

MOST_RECENT_BUILD=`curl -s "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/recent-builds?circle-token=$PERSONAL_TOKEN&limit=1"| grep 'build_num'|grep -o '\d.'|sed 's/,//g'|sort -r -n|head -n1`

curl -X POST "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/holmbergius/wildMeCypress/$MOST_RECENT_BUILD/retry?circle-token=$PERSONAL_TOKEN"
```